# APK created through VSTS does not run Galaxy S5

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, azure-pipelines

I have a sweet DevOps setup through VSTS and HockeyApp where my app builds, packages, signs, deploys to HockeyApp and is available for download.  But it does not run on my physical device!

The same app runs in an emulator (VS emulator).  It will also run on my physical device if I do Archive through Visual Studio 2015.

What are the exact steps involved in Archive operation through VS?  I thought that all it does is build + package (APK) + sign + zipalign.  But I see APKs created that way to be substantially bigger (~35 MB) than the ones created using VSTS (~20 MB) so something is amiss and I don't know what?

Please note that in both cases (i.e. Archive through VS or build through VSTS) the same project and configuration is used - so it must be something in the build/sign/zipalign process that is different.

Comment: You could always compare the VSTS task: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/XamarinAndroid The other thing to do is to use `adb logcat` to see what it is failing on so you can identify what step is missing. For example, perhaps it's not signing the `.apk` as the task might just be a build step and there's a separate sign/zipalign task. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/build

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  The problem was with disparate build configuration in my solution versus projects.

My solution has two projects: Core PCL and a Droid project.  My solution had a configuration ReleaseAzureQa which mapped to ReleaseAzureQa for PCL and Release for Droid.  This was because PCL cares about final release target but Droid project does not since it talks to the PCL.

In VSTS, however, build is set up for the Droid project and I was building it with ReleaseAzureQa configuration.  Now, interestingly, the build seemed to work and all completed OK but the resulting APK was much smaller.  I presume that it only contained the Droid project and not the Core PCL.  Once I aligned the configurations to match for both projects (i.e. set them to ReleaseAzureQa), all worked like a charm.